# Regular Expression for a 0.25 interval

Tags: regex

My aim is to write a regular expression for a decimal number where a valid number is one of
xx.0, xx.125, xx.25, xx.375, xx.5, xx.625, xx.75, xx.875 (i.e. measured in 1/8ths) The xx can be 0, 1 or 2 digits.

i have come up with the following regex:

```
^\d*\.?((25)|(50)|(5)|(75)|(0)|(00))?$
```

while this works for 0.25,0.5,0.75 it wont work for 0.225, 0.675 etc .

i assumed that the '?' would work in a case where there is preceding number as well.

Can someone point out my mistake

Edit : require the number to be a decimal !

Edit2 : i realized my mistake i was confused about the '?'. Thank you.

Comment: So you want to require a decimal place or no?  In your case you're basically saying 0 or more numbers with 0 or 1 decimal place and 25 or 50 or 5, etc... So the number 225 or 025 would be valid.

Comment: require the number to be a decimal.

Comment: Regular expressions are a great tool, but not for this. Also, are `xx.5`, `xx.50`, and `xx.500` all valid?

Comment: yes they are all valid. I am trying to validate the above scenario for input decimals in a php app. do you suggest another method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add another `\d*` after the literal `.` check `\.`

`^\d*\.?\d*((25)|(50)|(5)|(75)|(0)|(00))?$`

Answer (score 3):

I think it would probably just be easier to multiply the decimal part by 8, but you don't consider digits that lead the last two decimals in the regex.

```
^\d{0,2}\.(00?|(1|6)?25|(3|8)?75|50?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is: `\.?` indicates one optional `\.`, not a digit (or anything else, in this case).

About the `?` (question mark) operator: Makes the preceding item optional. Greedy, so the optional item is included in the match if possible. <sup>([source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html))</sup>

Comment: Thank you. that was my mistake fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d{0,2}\.(0|(1|2|6)?25|(3|6|8)?75|5)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values. Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).